# Compiled latest version of Vim, colorschemes not working any more

Tags: vim, color-theme

I took the following steps on an Ubuntu 10.04 machine.

First install some necessary dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome
```

Make sure you've got Mercurial and Python installed.
Then create a directory to put the source in:

```
$ mkdir ~/.build/hg
$ cd ~/.build/hg
```

Then clone the repository:

```
$ (date && hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim) 2>&1 |tee hg-vim.log
```

Start yer compilers!

```
$ make
```

Then install it in a certain location (I don't understand this completely):

```
$ sudo make install
```

Then create a symlink to make that Vim binary available everywhere.
To do that, first remove the existing symlink:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/vim
```

Then create the new one:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim
```

If I start my Vim now, it is the latest version (7.3.495) and it reads my .vimrc (I know because some settings in it are working). Doing

```
echo $MYVIMRC
```

Also gives me the path of my .vimrc.

Starting this version of Vim does not give me working colorschemes. The line numbers and background are colored but the text is not.

How could I further debug this?

**Edit**
The dump of

```
vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Apr 11 2012 11:13:46)
Included patches: 1-495
Compiled by niels@niels-desktop
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff 
+digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi 
+file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext 
-hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall 
+linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname 
+mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm 
-mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +mouse_urxvt +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme 
+netbeans_intg +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile
 -python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim 
+xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/directfb -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -    curses -    sl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm
```

Comment: Have you tried different color schemes? Type `:colorscheme ` and then tab your way through some available schemes (e.g. probably "default", "desert", ...) and see if they work (if none are found: try downloading a color scheme and put it in `~/.vim/colors/`). Perhaps you specify a non-standard color scheme in your `~/.vimrc` and the mainline Vim installation can't find it.

Comment: I did try that, to no avail. Only line numbers and background colors worked. I definitely also tried the default colorschemes (blue, desert, elflord etc..).

Comment: Give the output of `vim --version` in your question to show your compile-time options.

Comment: @DanielAndersson I added the output of vim --version

Comment: Not related to the original question but to the installation method: the steps `sudo rm /usr/bin/vim` and `ln -s /usr/local/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim` should not have been necessary and probably do not have any effect since /usr/local/bin should come before /usr/bin in your PATH.

Comment: Try starting vim as `vim -N -u NONE` to remove the effect of your ~/.vimrc and personal plugins, then execute `:syntax on` and `:edit` some file for which you expect to have syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like syntax highlighting is not activated. Your compile time options include `+syntax`, so that is not the problem.

Open a file that shoud be syntax highlighted and try the command `:syntax on` and see if anything happens.

You can also try to open a new document, enter

```
echo "hi there"
```

and then execute `:set ft=sh`. This should highlight the line according to shell script syntax.

Report any weirdness.